# libc6 dependency mismatch in Debian 9.12 stretch

Tags: linux, debian, dependencies, debian-stretch

I have the following libc6 dependency problem in Debian 9.12 stretch.

sudo apt install libc6-dev

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.24-11+deb9u4) but 2.27-6 is to be installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.24-11+deb9u4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix it?

EDIT1:
apt policy libc6

```
libc6:
  Installed: 2.27-6
  Candidate: 2.27-6
  Version table:
 *** 2.27-6 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.24-11+deb9u4 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
     2.24-11+deb9u1 500
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: this question was cross-posted on UL SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/570133/libc6-dependency-mismatch-in-debian-9-12-stretch and on SF: https://serverfault.com/questions/1004890/libc6-dependency-mismatch-in-debian-9-12-stretch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got help in another forum:
https://serverfault.com/a/1004951/302842

This was the solution to downgrade the problematic packages:

```
apt install libc6/stretch libc6-dev/stretch libc-dev-bin/stretch libc-bin/stretch locales/stretch sudo/stretch
```

The downgrade was successful!